# wordpress menu includes different domain randomly

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.1–en_GB, and have a live site which has been up and live for some months without issue.

48 hours ago it suddenly (or rather I noticed suddenly) started displaying some pages as unformatted (no css) lists of links and text.  The links on those pages were to another domain which directed to my site, but which has never been part of my site, and for which there is no direction within the site.

Loading and saving that one page fixed it on that page, and another page which was exhibiting the issue.

I redirected the external domain so that it would not point to my website.

Today it has exhibited the same behaviour, but with a subdomain which points to my site, but which again is not in use.  Again saving the page without making any edits 'fixed' the behaviour.

I'm not asking for a fix - but whether anyone has ever experienced a similar problem, or has a pointer towards where to look, and will report back what I find, in the hope it helps someone else if it ever occurs to them.

I didn't originally build the site - it has a load of plugins, not all active and disabling and removing plugins is definitely an option - but not a great one, since the problem is not predictable, so I have no firm way of knowing whether my actions have fixed the issue, and in the meantime my commercial site will not be functioning as desired (which I appreciate is occasionally the case anyway it would seem).

It sits in Amazon EC2.

sorry for the lack of precision, but I am truly stumped.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like your website may have been breached. to address the conflict of web pages not formatting is usually the ssl not being installed correctly on the server. but if you have a lot of plugins installed it's a huge security issue and the plugins may be causing the domain issue

1. the plugins may be causing a conflict within each other I would recommend removing the plugins that generally don't get used.
2. deactivate the plugins in use and reactivate them.
3. use word fence security plugin to run to a scan on your website.

when I had this problem it was because the ssl was not installed on my server correctly if not that, a breach may be the cause. I hope this helps.

Comment: The ssl is a lets encrypt certificate which automatically renewed.  It was renewed about 48 hours before the odd behaviour was first noticed, so this may be something to look at.  How could an SSL certificate affect the menus in the webpage though?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue started within that time frame as stated that makes me more confident that this is an ssl issue. Sometimes an ssl doesn’t install correctly on a server this can cause a conflict with how the layout in css and HTML is affected. this is common in some cases, while it’s happening with the current theme your using, some WordPress themes can bypass the ssl error, I would recommend getting a new ssl from let’s encrypt and removing the one that was auto renewed through let’s encrypt. This could simply fix the problem. If not feel free to share your findings on the issue.